# Tapping into unused Arduino pins with a shield in place

Tags: arduino, arduino

I am just getting started with Arduino...I figure this is kind of a newbie question but here goes.

I have a Duemilanove and the Sparkfun Speakjet shield.  I've got some breakaway headers (not the stackable headers) for connecting the Duemilanove with the Speakjet shield.  But then I want to interface a bunch of other stuff like switches and LEDs to the Arduino pins that are not used by the Speakjet shield.

Is it required to get the stackable headers to wire up my switches and LEDs to the Arduino pins?  Or is it advisable to just solder wires for my switches and LEDs onto the tiny nubs of the breakaway headers where they poke through the top of the Speakjet shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I looked the Sparkfun Speakjet shield did have stackable headers? Anyhoo aside from that moot point- It depends on how permanent your project is.

If you want to be able to use the Arduino again with different projects or shields - it's definitely recommended you get some stackable headers because of the cheap cost and ease of use.

If the project is relatively permanent and you don't intend on using the Arduino again in another project, soldering the wires on might be better for you, it will be cheaper in the short run and will be affective for making good connections - it's just fiddly to do and not the most professional looking way of hooking stuff up.

Comment: I had my own non-stackable headers already on hand, so that's what I was using.

I'm just going to solder onto the nubs of the header pins where they stick through the shield.  Not going for Underwriters Lab certification or anything like that so I think it will do.  Thanks!